# Is this a good way to communicate the result from the second page to the main page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop a simple application, a main page open a new page, that scan a QR code and then, when the second page get the QR, it has to notify to the main page the QR code and then it has to be closed automatically. Then the main page will do something with this code, for example, search on a database.

I want to use the MVVM, and this is my code:

```
class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService paramNavigationService)
    {
        ConstructorBase();

        _navigationService = paramNavigationService;
    }


    private void ConstructorBase()
    {
        EscanearCommand = new Command(() => Escanear(), () => true);
    }





    private INavigationService _navigationService;




    private string _codigoQr = "SIN QR EN PRINCIPAL";

    public string CodigoQr
    {
        get { return _codigoQr; }
        set
        {
            _codigoQr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }





    public ICommand EscanearCommand { get; private set; }

    private void Escanear()
    {
        _navigationService.AbrirPaginaEscaner(MyEventHandler);
    }


    private void MyEventHandler(string paramCodigoQr)
    {
        CodigoQr = paramCodigoQr;
    }
}





class ScannerViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _codigoQr = "SIN QR EN SCANNER";

    public string CodigoQr
    {
        get { return _codigoQr; }
        set
        {
            _codigoQr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}





interface INavigationService
{
    void AbrirPaginaEscaner(Action<string> paramAction);
}




class ViewNavigationService : INavigationService
{

    public ViewNavigationService(INavigation paramNavigation)
    {
        _navigation = paramNavigation;
    }





    private readonly INavigation _navigation;





    //Se necesita un evento al que suscribirse para notificar cuándo 



    public void AbrirPaginaEscaner(Action<string> paramAction)
    {
        ScannerView miScannerView = new ScannerView();
        ScannerViewModel miScannerViewModel = miScannerView.BindingContext as ScannerViewModel;


        miScannerViewModel.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedEventHandler;

        void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if((string.CompareOrdinal(e.PropertyName, nameof(miScannerViewModel.CodigoQr)) == 0)
                    && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(miScannerViewModel.CodigoQr) == false)

                        paramAction(miScannerViewModel.CodigoQr);
            }
            finally
            {
                miScannerViewModel.PropertyChanged -= PropertyChangedEventHandler;
                _navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
            }
        }



        _navigation.PushModalAsync(miScannerView);
    }
}
```

The idea it is to have a navigation service, that implements an interface, so for test purposes I could use another implementation to don't to scan the QR.

In the service, I subscribe to the event of the scanner view model, I check if the QR is set, and if it is set, I close the page. I close the page here, in the service, because I think the page scanner shouldn't close itself when a QR is read, so it can be use in another cases in which I don't want to close it.

In the service, if the QR is read, the it unsubscribe to the event of the scanner view model to ensure the page and the view model will reacollected by the garbage collector.

Then, the service use the action that receive by parameter, this makes that the main view model do what it has to do when the QR is read.

I think this approach is interesting because the scanner view model has not to notifiy events neither send messages with MessagingCenter. It is enough with the notify property changed, that it is needed to update the UI.

Also, in the main view model only needs to indicate the action that is has to be done when the QR is read, so the code is very simply.

In this way, I can add more navigations options and if the caller need information from the second page, it can be notify in a similar way.

But really it is a simple project that I wanted to use to start learning about Xamarin Forms, so perhaps there are another alternatives and it would be good to know another ways to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: use an event.  Use a callback method.  Use MessagingCenter.  Use a navigation service from a MVVM framework like PRISM, etc.  There are many, many ways you can do this

Comment: I think the question fits better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com